# use a string to create an object

Tags: php, object

I have the following object creation line in PHP:

```
$countryTargetSearchParameter = new CountryTargetSearchParameter(array(new CountryTarget('JP')));
```

I am trying to replace it with:

```
$countryTargetSearchParameter = new CountryTargetSearchParameter(array($LocArray));
```

where $LocArray is equal to new CountryTarget('JP'). However, I am not able to get this to work. Can I get some help please.

Thank you
Jai

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? Why don't you just create the array within your constructor rather than attempting to pass in it at the point of creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CountryTargetSearchParameter {
    public function __construct(array $array_with_string) {
        $this->new_object = new CountryTarget($array_with_string[0]);
    }
}
$array_with_string = array('JP');
$test = new CountryTargetSearchParameter($array_with_string);
```

Or, much cleaner, and using a string for the class:

```
class CountryTargetSearchParameter {
    public function __construct($name_of_class, $parameter) {
        $this->new_object = new $name_of_class($parameter);
    }
}
$test = new CountryTargetSearchParameter('CountryTarget', 'JP');
```

Comment: .Thanks Stephen. The answer I was looking for was very simple. I just had to use the eval function

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it with eval.  Have you tried my method?